# Troubleshooting spring profiles at runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-profiles

I'm currently maintaining a legacy codebase where the following Spring profile configuration has been specified in the application context:

```
spring.profiles.active=addressbook-[usermanager|webservices],entrypoint-[form|saml]
```

The question is: how do I read what is specified in this example for `spring.profiles.active`?

Am I right in thinking that there are 4 possible profile definitions here? Namely:

```
addressbook-usermanager, entrypoint-form
addressbook-webservices, entrypoint-form
addressbook-usermanager, entrypoint-saml
addressbook-webservices, entrypoint-saml
```

Is there a way to turn on logging to see which profile is chosen and which beans get loaded for a particular profile? And if not, why they didn't get loaded?

I'm plowing through [this blog post](http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/) and any other kind of documentation that I can find, but I haven't found anything specific to the profile specification syntax above. Is there any documentation available?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any support in Spring for the syntax that you've described above. I believe that the configuration you've described will give you two active profiles:

- `addressbook-[usermanager|webservices]`
- `entrypoint-[form|saml]`

You can query the currently active profiles using [`Environment.getActiveProfiles()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html#getActiveProfiles--). To get hold of the `Environment` instance, you can use Spring's auto-wiring or implement [`EnvironmentAware`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/EnvironmentAware.html).

You might also want to look at `ProfileCondition`. There's no logging in it, but you could use the debugger to see beans being included or excluded based on their `@Profile` annotation.

Comment: Never mind. I failed to realize that this just meant to imply that I had to choose one of each option explicitly in my configuration. As you rightly mentioned, Spring has nothing to do/does not care about what name is in there. So yeah... OSI layer 8 error *facepalm*. Thanks again!

Comment: ... I need coffee XD.